# Create new Dataframe for every loop with a defined amount of csv files in Julia

Tags: dataframe, loops, julia

Hi everyone and thanks for reading!

Let's assume I have a directory (C:\Users\me\Files) with e.g. 20 CSV-Files with different Names (File1.csv, ABC.csv, ... x7b_320.csv)

I want to loop over a those files and put a specific amount of them into different DataFrames. Lets say df_1 should contain the first 5 CSV-Files  and be stored in that DataFrame, then in the next iteration CSV-Files should be stored in df_2 and so on until all CSV-Files a stored.

I have no idea how do I do that in Julia... can anyone help or has some good ideas / links?

Thanks so much!

Edit:
I am not sure if my memory is suffient for that task, does is might be better to use some kind of database or how to handle large files with DataFrames

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Dict("df_$i" => CSV.read(string.("File", x, ".csv"), DataFrame)
     for (i, x) in enumerate(Iterators.partition(1:20, 5)))
```

And get a dictionary of data frames that you want with the names you asked for as keys and data frames as values.

If something in the code is not clear please ask in the comment and I can clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have to apologize for not clearifing my question. The Files in the Folder are randomly named and not "File1", etc. Additionally i was wondering how to handle large data. Because i am afraid when loading all the data into DataFrames i will run out of memory. Is there a simple solution for using DataFrames with Data of 400GB in total?

Comment: Regarding the fact that the files have different names - you can just replace the part of the code that generates the file names with a list of names that you want to load. Regarding large memory footprint - the answer will depend on the exact operation you need to perform. Assuming a typical use-case, I would convert all the CSV files into a single Arrow file and then work with it as a single big data frame (the downside is that then the columns of a data frame will be read-only, but given your data has 400GB I assume that this should be acceptable).